# How to calculate mean pairwise dissimilarities 'within' and 'between' groups using 'meandist' function in r

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, mean, vegan

```
require(vegan)
```

My dissimilarity matrix (100*100 observations) is based on the Raup-Crick metric proposed by Chase et al. (2011). This matrix is supposed to have negative dissimilarities- that's not the problem here, do not be alarmed.

```
RC_2015 <- read.csv(file="RC_2015.csv")

       9    9     9      12    12   12     12    12   12    12     12
   9 -0.91 -1.00 -1.00 -0.99 -1.00 -0.99 -0.11 -0.08 -0.27 -0.16 -1.00
   9 -0.90 -0.98 -1.00 -0.98 -1.00 -0.97 -0.80 -0.90 -0.86 -0.94 -0.99
   9 -0.94 -1.00 -0.98 -0.96 -0.96 -0.99 -0.63 -0.21 -0.41 -0.31 -1.00
  12 -0.94 -1.00 -0.99 -0.99 -1.00 -0.93 -0.65  0.52  0.09 -0.60 -1.00
  12 -0.55 -0.98 -0.98 -0.99 -1.00 -1.00 -0.63  0.28  0.02 -0.31 -0.99
  12 -0.82 -0.98 -0.98 -0.96 -0.99 -0.99  0.17  0.28  0.02  0.15 -0.99
  12 -0.33 -0.50  0.05 -0.55 -0.82  0.07  0.09  0.97  0.86  0.66 -0.86
  12 -0.63 -0.99 -0.92 -0.98 -1.00 -0.97 -0.36  0.51  0.32 -0.02 -1.00
  12 -0.82 -0.98 -0.98 -0.86 -0.99 -0.97 -0.27  0.28  0.02  0.15 -0.99
  12 -1.00 -0.97 -0.96 -0.51 -0.51 -0.59  0.32  0.73 -0.27 -0.16 -1.00
```

A snippet of what the matrix looks like

Group data according to factor (in this case, the factor is age)

```
groups <- factor(c(rep(1,10), rep(2,10), rep(3,10), rep(4,10), rep(5,10), rep(6,10), rep(7,10), rep(8,10), rep(9,10), rep(10,10)), labels = c("5","9","12","15","19","23","27","31","35","38"),exclude = NULL)
```

I need to calculate the mean dissimilarity 'within' and 'between' groups. That's where the 'meandist' function comes in.

```
meandist(dist, grouping...)
```

I'm following the function's code step-by-step instead, because I get an error message when I use the function.

```
dist<-RC_2015[,-1]

grouping <- groups

grow <- grouping[as.dist(row(as.matrix(dist)))] 
gcol <- grouping[as.dist(col(as.matrix(dist)))] 

first <- as.numeric(grow) >= as.numeric(gcol) 
cl1 <- ifelse(first, grow, gcol) 
cl2 <- ifelse(!first, grow, gcol) 

n <- table(grouping) 
take <- matrix(TRUE, nlevels(grouping), nlevels(grouping)) 
diag(take) <- n > 1 
take[upper.tri(take)] <- FALSE 
out <- matrix(NA, nlevels(grouping), nlevels(grouping)) 
## Get output matrix 
tmp <- tapply(dist, list(cl1, cl2), mean) 
out[take] <- tmp[!is.na(tmp)] 
out[upper.tri(out)] <- t(out)[upper.tri(out)] 
rownames(out) <- colnames(out) <- levels(grouping) 
class(out) <- c("meandist", "matrix") 
attr(out, "n") <- table(grouping) 
out
```

Error message

```
 tmp <- tapply(dist, list(cl1, cl2), mean)
```

Error in tapply(dist, list(cl1, cl2), mean) : 
  arguments must have same length

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: It seems that your `dist` is a matrix, but it should be a `"dist"` object. What happens if you first use `dist <- as.dist(dist)`, or directly `dist <- as.dist(RC_2015[,-1])`?

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly now. I thought there was something wrong with my grouping but it's because I converted the distance object to a matrix before doing the computation.